# useState console log return undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm slowly starting to use React hooks and I don't understand why console.log returns me undefined, In general idea is to pass some string to function, and then inside function set new state, and pass it via props to another component. For now I wish to console.log the result but it keep's showing me undefined

```
const [moduleConfig, setModuleConfig] = React.useState("")

function handleClose(e, moduleConfig) {
    setMenuEl(null)
    setModuleConfig(moduleConfig)
  }

<MenuItem onClick={e => handleClose(e, "light")}>
                  <Link
                    to="/module" 
                    href="/module"
                    > {console.log(moduleConfig)}
                      Set Leds
                  </Link>
                </MenuItem>
```

EDIT:

Oki maybe I wasn't clear enough, So i wanted to console.log it to see if it changes value after clicking on element, but orginally I wish to pass it to the component like this:

```
<Route
            exact
            path="/module"
            render={() => <SetModule classes={classes} moduleConfig={moduleConfig}/>}
          />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a working code example which shows the issue it's hard to see why your console isn't outputting the correct value.

Here's a working example where the console outputs `light`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [moduleConfig, setModuleConfig] = useState("");

  const handleClose = (e, moduleConfig) => {
    setModuleConfig(moduleConfig);
  };

  console.log("moduleConfig:", moduleConfig);

  return <button onClick={e => handleClose(e, "light")}>Click me</button>;
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-khayyam-ec0x2)

Comment: it works now, but have no idea why, changed it to arrow function and started to work, but then changed back to normal function and weirdly it is still working... anyway thanks for help, problem solved:) btw so then I can just pass this value to component like ```<SetModule classes={classes} moduleConfig={moduleConfig}/>``` right?

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to then pass `moduleConfig` down like you would with a normal state item or prop.

Answer (score -2):

[`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) doesn't produce a value. It just outputs the message to the web console. If want to insert a `moduleConfig` value in your markup, do it directly:

```
<MenuItem onClick={e => handleClose(e, "light")}>
  <Link
    to="/module" 
    href="/module"
  > {moduleConfig} Set Leds
  </Link>
</MenuItem>
```